# Uncache dynamic blocks in cms page using Lesti FPC

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I have two blocks that deliver dynamic data, set up in a CMS page.

One block is a button that needs to look activated if a DB record is found and says "Download (PDF)" or be grayed out with text that says "Download Unavailable" in the button if no data is found.

The other block is a table displaying the record if found, if not then it says "Sorry no results found".

The problem is my CMS pages are cached with Lesti FPC in config:

[image: Lesti FPC Cachable actions]

And adding the blocks to Dynamic Blocks or Lazy Load blocks seem to get overridden by the Cachable Actions settings, so the blocks are cached along with the CMS page and never get re-rednered.  So I am able to see results in one browser and the same results in another browser which they should be different for each session.  Removing cms_page_view from Cachable actions work, but that defeats the purpose of caching cms pages, there has to be a way to do it.

#### CMS Page Content:

```
  <div class="items-section">

        <div class="hero-item-1">

            <h1>Your Results!</h1>

            <p>Before leaving this page, download the pdf below.</p>
                
            {{block type="reader/scannerresults" name="scannerresults" template="reader/results-download-button.phtml" buttonTitle="Download your Results" buttonCopy="DOWNLOAD RESULTS (PDF)" disabledButtonCopy="DOWNLOAD UNAVAILABLE"}}

        </div>

        <div class="hero-item-2">
            {{block type="reader/scannerresults" name="scannerresults" template="reader/results-table.phtml" noResultsFoundCopy="Sorry no results were found."}}
        </div>

    </div>
    
</div>
```

#### Design > Layout Update XML

Just a pointer to CSS

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/reader/scanner-results.css</name><params/></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used Lesti in quite some time, but can you declare those blocks as dynamic if you add them to the page using Layout Update XML? Make sure the block names are unique. Something like this:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/text" name="some.line">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<h1>Your Results!</h1>
                <p>Before leaving this page, download the pdf below.</p>]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="reader/scannerresults" name="scannerresults" template="reader/results-download-button.phtml"/>
    <block type="reader/scannerresults" name="scannerresults" template="reader/results-table.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Have you tried that?

Tom

Comment: Nice, got it working mostly by adding the blocks to layout update xml, re-rendering the blocks each time and added the block names to the Lesti Dynamic Blocks config.  it is displaying the the 2nd block twice but I think I know whats wrong with that.

Comment: I found [this article](https://gordonlesti.com/dynamic-or-lazy-blocks-in-a-cms-page-with-lesti-fpc/) from lesti so adding this as well for more specificity

Comment: Yes, that article explains it all. Glad you got it working.